# How can i test facebook rule i have created?

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

For example if i set rule to trigger my server when clicks in 
greater than 1000 . it is possible to test it in sandbox tool ,
without creating real ads with money ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Sandboxed ads don't receive clicks.